# Solving a linear, inhomogeneous, ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this?
$\newcommand{\d}[0]{{\rm d}}$
$$a\frac{\d^2y}{\d x^2}+b\frac{\d y}{\d x}+cy=d\\
a,b,c\in \mathbb R;\qquad y\equiv y(x);\qquad d\equiv d(x)$$
I know how to solve when $d=0$ by assuming a solution $y=e^{\alpha x}$ and then finding $\alpha$, for simplicity you can let $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $f(a_1)=f(a_2)=0$ where $a_1,a_2$ be $f$'s two roots.Therefore in the case of $d=0$, $y=c_1e^{a_1x}+c_2e^{a_2x}$

---

- Actually I'm trying to solve: (from Alternating Current(AC) through a Capacitor, Resistor and Inductor)
  $$L\frac{\d^2q}{\d t^2}+R\frac{\d q}{\d t}+\frac qc=v_0\sin \omega t$$
  and: (from Simple Harmonic Motion with a Spring, Damping and External agent's force)
  $$ m\frac{\d^2x}{\d t^2} +b \frac{\d x}{\d t}+k x =F_0\cos \omega_dt$$
- Where c:Capacitance, R:Resistance, L:Inductance, $v_0$:Maximum Voltage, $\omega$:AC frequency  and t:time.
- Also m:mass, b:damping constant, k:spring constant, $F_0$:maximum external force, $\omega_d$:external agent's frequency and t:time.
- The analogy is in $L\leftrightarrow m,R\leftrightarrow b, 1/c\leftrightarrow k, F_0\leftrightarrow v_0,\omega\leftrightarrow \omega_d$.
- Also some useful shorthand notations are:
  $$X_L=L\omega\qquad X_c=\frac1{c\omega}\qquad Z=\sqrt{R^2+(X_c-X_L)^2}\qquad \phi=\arctan\frac{X_c-X_L}R$$
- My book uses the assumption $q=q_0\sin(\omega t+\theta)$ but I clearly see it's just working backwards from the result. I wonder how physicists arrived at the result for the first time?
- Mysteriously another method involves vectors/phasers/complex numbers and Pythagoreas theorem!

Comment: Can you tell us what $f$ is? And how are $a$ and $b$ from $f$ related to the roots of $f$? They can't be the same

Comment: @Hrodelbert the auxillary equation, if anyone wanted to use shorthand notation for that quadratic in his answer.

Comment: Do you want a solution for generic $d \in \mathbb{R}$ or something even more general?

Comment: @Hrodelbert let me specify in the question instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the RHS are trig functions, you can refer to the [Method of undertermined coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients).

Basically, you make a "guess" of the solution (after finding the homogeneous solution):

$$ y_p = A_1 \sin (\omega t) + A_2 \cos (\omega t)$$

Then take the derivatives and plug them back into the equation to find the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** This solution was written for an earlier incarnation of the original question, in which $d$ was a constant, not a function.

**Hint:** Can you find one particular solution of the differential equation? (**Hint:** If the first two terms on the LHS were absent and $c \neq 0$, the equation would reduce to $c y = d$, which is easy to solve. For which kinds of functions do those first two terms vanish?)

Comment: please reread my question whereby i mention one particular solution

Comment: you mean $y=d/c$ where $y',y''=0$??

Comment: The solution in the original equation is a solution to the differential equation for the particular parameter value $d = 0$ (i.e., for the corresponding homogeneous equation). By "particular solution", I mean a *single* solution for general $d$.

Comment: Yes, (at least when $c \neq 0$), $y = \frac{d}{c}$ is certainly a solution to the given equation. Now, how can you use that solution together with your solution to the corresponding homogeneous equation $ay'' + by' + cy = 0$ to produce the general solution to the original equation $ay'' + by' + cy + d$?

Comment: you mean $c_1e^{a_1x}+c_2e^{a_2x}+d/c$??

Comment: Does that solve the o.d.e.?

Comment: (Also, be careful, the $a$ and $b$ in the original o.d.e. are in general not the same as the coefficients in the exponential functions.)

Comment: not those mentioned above/below. I changed them to $a_1$ & $a_2$.

Comment: will you edit the title again?

Comment: I think it's still okay, "constant coefficients" applies just to the coefficients of the $y^{(k)}$, not to the function of $t$ on the r.h.s.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y(t) = u(t) + \frac{d}{c}$.

Comment: please re-see the question :)